# how to set the text box to accept the values as ranges?

Tags: html, angularjs

I want a input box to accept only value which is of type (20-40), like that not single numbers between 20-40 , i am telling the user that to define the range of that particular input box ?

can any one help me in doing the same. thanks.

[example of my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYFlc.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i have added the image of my requirement @Paulie_D

Answer (score 0):

There is an input element type named `number`. Hope this might be helpful for you.

It has attributes

1. Min - Minimum value
2. Max - Maximum Value
3. Step - Increment By.

```html
<input type="number" min="10" max="20" step="2" value="10"/>
```

Comment: my requirement is not that one. for example

Comment: Red- 0-40 green 41-80 white 81-100 like this the text boxes should accept

Answer (score 0):

In HTLM5 there is an option to set range bounds.
Please check this https://jsfiddle.net/ozgsn5pn/2/

```html
<h3>A demonstration of how to access a Slider Control</h3>
<input type="range" id="myRange" min="20" max="40" value="30">
<p>Click the button to get the value of the slider control.</p>
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
<p><strong>Note:</strong> input elements with type="range" are not supported in IE 9 and earlier versions.</p>
<p id="demo"></p>
```

Comment: using angular js how can we obtain that?

Answer (score 0):

hi try this code to validate input box ranging from 20 to 40.

```
    <script>
    function validate() {
    var n= document.getElementById("txtnum").value;
    if(!(n >= 19&& n <= 41))
       document.getElementById("txtnum").value="";
       alert("please enter valid no from 20-40");
    }
    </script>
    <input type="number" id="txtnum" onblur="validate();">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (# 20-40):

JavaScript:

```
    function myFunction() {
        var x = document.getElementById("input").value;
        if (x<20 || x>40) {
        document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = "Choose a number between 20 and 40";
        }  else document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML = " ";
    }
```

HTML

```
Example: <input id="input" onchange="myFunction()" placeholder="Choose number between 20 and 40">

<p id="warning"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function checkrange()    
{
   var input=parseInt(document.getElementById("number").value);
   //alert(input);
   if(input<=10)
   {
      // alert('hi');
       document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "one";
       //document.getElementById("mySelect").selectedIndex="1";
     
       
   }
   else if((input>10)&&(input<20))
   {
       //alert('h')
        document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "two";
   }
   
   else if((input>20)&&(input<30))
   {
       //alert('h')
        document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "three";
   }
   else
   {
       alert('Invalid Range')
       document.getElementById("mySelect").value = "empty";
   }


}
```

```html
<form>
Please enter a number in textfield :
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="empty"></option>
    <option value="one">1-10</option>
  <option value="two">11-20</option>
  <option value="three">21-30</option>
  
</select>
<input type="number" id="number" onkeyup="checkrange();" placeholder="Enter a number between 1-30" min="1" max="30" style="width: 200px;">
  </form>
```

Hi,

Thanks for posting the question.

I have a slight different approach to your answer and may be you can also adopt it.

What I did is that the user has to input a value or a number and based on that value the select box option changes.

Run the above code snippet.May be that helps.

Thanks and happy coding :)